# Model class robovise.models.RoboProcessedFiles doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS Celery

Tags: python, django, celery

I am using celery in my django project.
2 issues, the autodiscover task doesn't discover my task under *robovise/tasks.py* so I had to explicitly pass the path of the tasks file in the `include` argument of `Celery` instance.
Then when I try calling the task in my django shell I get this error in Celery:

```
[2021-08-17 16:26:36,312: ERROR/MainProcess] Task robovise.tasks.process_new_users_resp[5763be00-77d4-4705-bb9a-6e06f2b03464] raised unexpected: RuntimeError("Model class robovise.models.RoboProcessedFiles doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/cyzanfar/Desktop/beagle/projects/financial_services/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 450, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/cyzanfar/Desktop/beagle/projects/financial_services/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 731, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/cyzanfar/Desktop/beagle/projects/financial_services/financial_services/robovise/tasks.py", line 5, in process_new_users_resp
    from robovise.models import RegisteredUser
  File "/Users/cyzanfar/Desktop/beagle/projects/financial_services/financial_services/robovise/models.py", line 12, in <module>
    class RoboProcessedFiles(models.Model):
  File "/Users/cyzanfar/Desktop/beagle/projects/financial_services/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 113, in __new__
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Model class robovise.models.RoboProcessedFiles doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

I've seen many post talking about this issue but have not found any solution. It's really strange as I have the same setup in another project and it works fine.

project structure:

```
├── financial_services
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── celery.py
│   ├── settings
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── base.py
│   │   ├── development.py
│   │   └── production.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── manage.py
├── requirements.txt
└── robovise
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── admin.py
    ├── apps.py
    ├── constants.py
    ├── helpers.py
    ├── migrations
    ├── models.py
    ├── seed.py
    ├── services.py
    ├── tasks.py
    ├── tests.py
    └── views.py
```

*celery.py*

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from celery import Celery

# Set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
# os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'financial_services.settings')

app = Celery('financial_services', include=['robovise.tasks'])

# Using a string here means the worker doesn't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

and here is *robovise/tasks.py*:

```
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task
def process_new_users_resp():
    from robovise.models import RegisteredUser

    print("IN TASK!!!")
    RegisteredUser.fetch_and_update_resp()

    return True
```

Also my settings.base.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'robovise',
]
```

*/robovise/apps.py*

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class RoboviseConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'robovise'
```

*/robovise/models.py*

```
from django.db import models
from .services import (
    upload_req, read_res, read_primeid,
    read_positions, read_costbasis, read_acct_value,
    read_non_trade_trn, read_trade_trn
)
from django.db import transaction
from .tasks import process_new_users_resp


class RoboProcessedFiles(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    file_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)

    @classmethod
    def processed_file(cls, file_type):
        return RoboProcessedFiles.objects \
            .filter(file_type=file_type) \
            .order_by('-created_at').first()
    ...
```

Starting celery using:

```
 celery -A financial_services worker --pool=gevent --concurrency=500 --loglevel=INFO
```

and then the python shell where I call a function that calls my task:

```
 python manage.py shell -i ipython --settings=financial_services.settings
```

Comment: Did you comment this out on purpose `# os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'financial_services.settings')`? It is needed for Celery to be able to autodiscover the tasks modules per app. Also, can you share your `robovise/apps.py` and maybe a layout of your `robovise/models.py`?

Comment: hey. with or without it I still get the same error. I did export `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`. Updating my question now with robovise/apps.py and /models.py

Comment: I notice you have `from __future__ import absolute_import`. What versions of Python, Django and Celery are you using?

Comment: python: 3.8.5, django: 3.2.6, celery: 5.1.2. I tried with and without that import. Still same issue